# nodemon - ignore the file and path

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am using node js and the nodemon module.

**Problem:** If I change file in front-end the server will be automatically restarted.

**Expected:** If I change the few js or few files inside the path it should not restart the server.

**I tried the following code:**

nodemon --ignore 'public/javascripts/template_files/*.js'

But the above code not working. If I change any js files inside the template_files folders means the server restarting again and again.

Comment: What starts the server — your typing in this command, or using a script like `npm start`? If the latter, make sure the `start` field in `package.json` is set to the proper `nodemon` command (like you have listed above).

Comment: I tried two methods in command line: 1) nodemon --ignore 'public/javascripts/template_files/*.js'
 2)npm start

Comment: I  checked in package.json . I already changed that one.  Like this:  "scripts": {
   "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },

Comment: we use a similar command it works fine. Can you try two things. 1 - Provide the folder name only . 2 - if the folder name does not work try the config file approach

Comment: @RSKMR you just wrote the problem. Your start script needs to be `nodemon --ignore 'public/javascripts/template_files/*.js' ./bin/www`. Do not use nodemon from the command line, just `npm start`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the comments I now have enough information to explain what's going on.

In your `package.json`, your start script needs to look like this:

```
"scripts" : {
    "start" : "nodemon ./bin/www --ignore 'public/javascripts/template_files/*.js'"
},
```

That means, when you run `npm start`, the command `nodemon` should be run (monitoring all file changes), executing the `./bin/www` file, but not monitoring those specific JS files. If a file (other than the ignored files) changes, re-execute the `./bin/www` file.

What you were doing before was trying to execute `nodemon --ignore 'public/javascripts/template_files/*.js'` from the command line, which won't execute any particular file (IIRC), and also leaving the start script as `nodemon ./bin/www`, which will not ignore the files you want ignored.

Make the change to your `package.json` and only use `npm start`. Do not type `nodemon` directly into the command line, there is no need.